# how to remove the vertical space between to btn-groups nested in another btn-goup?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, radio-group

I am making a radio group like this image:

[image]

but i want to remove the vertical space between the last two `btn-groups`.

How can I accomplish this?

my html:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<label class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2011" type="radio">2011
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2012" type="radio">2012
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2013" type="radio">2013
  </label>
  <label class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2014" type="radio">2014
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2015" type="radio">2015
      </label>
    </label>
  </label>
  <label class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2016" type="radio">2016
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2017" type="radio">2017
      </label>
    </label>
  </label>
</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but you could do the following:

```
<label class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2011" type="radio">2011
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
     <input name="year" value="2012" type="radio">2012
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2013" type="radio">2013
  </label>
  <label class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn-group">
       <label class="btn btn-default">
         <input name="year" value="2014" type="radio">2014
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2015" type="radio">2015
      </label>
    </label>
  </label>
  <label class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="group2">
    <label class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2016" type="radio">2016
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2017" type="radio">2017
      </label>
    </label>
  </label>
</label>
```

With this CSS:

```
#group2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```css
.group-4{
  margin-bottom:0px;  
}
.group-4>label{
  margin-bottom:0px;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<label class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2011" type="radio">2011
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2012" type="radio">2012
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="year" value="2013" type="radio">2013
  </label>
  <label class="btn-group group-4" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2014" type="radio">2014
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2015" type="radio">2015
      </label>
    </label>
  </label>
  <label class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2016" type="radio">2016
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="year" value="2017" type="radio">2017
      </label>
    </label>
  </label>
</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```